# Why a Null Pointer Exception in Spark JobScheduler?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I get this exception:

```java
Exception in thread "pool-6-thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:173)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Any idea what may be causing this? I'm running a Spark Streaming job with a custom receiver. The receiver stops but there is data still pending to be processed.

So it waits for data to be processed before stopping. since stopGracefully is set to true.

But before all data is processed, I get this error.